# How to check DataFrameWriter save() 's final writing result without reading the output table in Spark?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Right now I uses Scala + Spark to write my DataFrame: df to KustoCluster, and I just found that there's no callback option for DataFrameWriter.save(), this is the code I have

```
    var writer = df.write.format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.synapse.datasource")
      .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", linkedServiceName)
      .option("kustoDatabase", database)
      .option("kustoTable", table)

    writer.mode(mode).save()
```

Sometimes the data frame df could be huge, and it will take some time to run and may fail after a while, however I don't think there is a way to check the final save() result for DataFrameWriter, so if that finally failed, there's no way to tell in the Spark job.
Someone suggested I could try to read the output table to check if the save() process finally succeed. But it will be hard and time consuming. So is there any way or functions I could use to check the writing result?

Find a way to check the dataframe write result without reading the output table.

Comment: Every distributed write operation by SPARK writes a `_SUCCESS` file in the output location. You can test for the presence of this file which indicates that the write was successfully. This file is always written to the location once the write is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you trigger a write, Spark creates an action and the job starts materializing itself into stages and tasks and the progress / status of the job will ultimately be logged in the Spark UI. You can create utilities to keep a view of the Spark UI active when the job is running/ until user stops the cluster.

But assuming you don't have access to the Spark UI, then one way is to wrap the `save` logic in a method that calls the `writer` object which implements a try-catch block as so:

```scala
def safeSave(df: DataFrame, writer: DataFrameWriter[Row], mode: SaveMode): Boolean = {
  try {
    writer.mode(mode).save()
    true
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      println(s"Failed to save DataFrame: ${e.getMessage}")
      false
  }
}
```

and then call the method which returns a boolean `True` if your save is successful.

```scala
val isSuccess = safeSave(df, writer, mode)
```

As mentioned in a comment, if there is a use case where you are writing the data to a Hadoop like file systems (HDFS, S3 etc.) then you can check for the existence of the zero-byte `_SUCCESS` file which marks as an indicator for successful writes.

Below is a gist:

```scala
// Create a Hadoop Configuration and FileSystem
val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

// Define the path to the _SUCCESS file (write location)
val successFilePath = new Path(s"$pathToOutputDirectory/_SUCCESS")

// Check if the _SUCCESS file exists
if (fs.exists(successFilePath)) {
  println("The save operation completed successfully.")
} else {
  println("The save operation did not complete successfully.")
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that even in Hadoop-based file systems, the `_SUCCESS` file is not guaranteed to be created in all scenarios. For example, if the write operation is interrupted or fails for some reason, the `_SUCCESS` file may not be created, so instead of manually checking for it you can utilize a try-catch block.

Additionally, certain configurations or custom output formats (like NoSQL databases) may choose not to create a `_SUCCESS` file.

Comment: I'd recommend using the [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.13/scala/util/Try.html) type and function over a plain `try`, so `Try[Unit]` becomes the return type. It keeps the exception, including its full stack trace, which can be of interest to the calling code, and communicates more clearly that the operation can fail.

Comment: "if the write operation is interrupted or fails for some reason, the _SUCCESS file may not be created". Exactly, it is only created if a job is SUCCESSFUL. note that s3a and manifest (abfs, gcs) committers put some JSON in there with useful stats about what happened..

Comment: also, spark queries which update an existing table (i forget what, INSERT UPDATE?) dont' have _SUCCESS files as they write into a _temp subdir and rename outputs in partitions, but not the _SUCCESS file. pity

Answer (score 0):

To preface this, I am not familiar with Kusto, but have used Spark extensively.

`save()` is a terminal operation in Spark, so it causes Spark jobs to be created and run in the Spark environment (be it a cluster or standalone). Being a terminal operation, `save()` also blocks the current thread until it is completed or fails.

As another answer mentions, you can wrap your call to save in a try-catch block and catch any exceptions and use the presence of an exception to say if a failure has occurred. I'd recommend going a step further and using the [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.13/scala/util/Try.html) type to preserve the failure exception so you can better react to it.

For example:

```scala
def trySave(df: DataFrame, writer: DataFrameWriter[Row], mode: SaveMode): Try[Unit] = Try { 
  writer.mode(mode).save() 
}

// This would be used like so:
trySave(df, writer, mode) match {
  case Success(_) => // do something on successfully writing
  case Failure(cause) => // do something on failure, with full access to exception
}
```

Having a read of the [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.13/scala/util/Try.html) documentation will give a good overview of what it precisely is, but in short: it wraps a block of code that can succeed or throw exceptions and returns either a `Success` containing the returned data or `Failure` containing thrown exception. In the case of `save()` no value is returned on a success which is equal to `Unit` in Scala.